# mdadm raid 5 pairity check control / new behaviors in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: cron, raid, systemd, mdadm

It looks like there's been some changes in when mdadm does parity checks and how it is controlled.  It used to start the first Sunday of the month at about 1AM and was started by a cron entry.  Now it looks like it's starting at about 5AM on the first Sunday and has a new features that pauses it (when the system is being used?) and then restarts it at weird (random?) times like 8AM on a weekday.  I don't see any cron entries for this anymore so I'm not sure how it's being controlled.

Can someone tell me...

- Where are the start, pause, restart behaviors controlled from in 20.04
- What causes it to pause
- Generally, how is this supposed to work now

I'd like to change the behaviors so it restarts early AM instead of during the day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

mdadm checks are now controlled by systemd in a more complicated process than previously.

The systemd timer starts the mdadm check service at 1AM on the first Sunday of the month but has a random start time of 24H, meaning it starts anytime on that day (which seems kind of dumb).  This can be changed with the command `sudo systemctl edit --full mdcheck_start.timer` and editing the `RandomizedDelaySec` field to something like `10m`.

When the check service starts, it runs `mdcheck --duration 6 hours` meaning that the check will run for 6 hours and then pause (aka stop and save the stopping point so it can be continued later).  This can be seen with the command `systemctl cat mdcheck_start.service`

Systemd runs the continuation check every day at a 12hour randomized time (midnight - noon).  To changed this do `sudo systemctl edit --full mdcheck_continue.timer`.  The `OnCalendar` field and `RandomizedDelaySec` can be changed to have this continue at more specific days/times.

When the continuation service runs it calls `mdcheck --continue --duration 6` to continue checking for another 6 hours.  This can be seen with the command `systemctl cat mdcheck_continue.service`

Comment: This is great information.  Can you point at the written documentation that describes how all this works?

Comment: I don't think I ever found any docs with great details.  Most of this came from digging through systemd, following the logic and doing a few simple experiments.

Comment: So is this "check" the same as echoing "check" to the sync_action file for my md array?  So I guess this means that it's doing a full scrub of the array once a month, so it's not really necessary for me to do it myself.  Would you happen to know if/where the logs for these scrubs are kept?  I'd like to educate myself and be able to better keep an eye on things.

Comment: Start and stop will be found in `/var/log/syslog`.  You can see the array status with `cat /proc/mdstat`.